# Invalid Token 'String' in class, struct or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having error with my code "Invalid Token 'String' in class, struct or interface member declaration" please help.

```
private void string InsertRecords(TextBox textboxname, string qryname, string parametername)
{
    string msg;

    if (textboxname.Text != "")
    {
        ConnString conn = new ConnString();
        string MyConn = conn.GetConn(); // Get Connection String

        using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(MyConn))
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = qryname;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + parametername, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textboxname.Text;
                cmd.Connection = sqlconn;
                sqlconn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                msg = $"<strong>Record Successfully Added!</strong>";
                return msg;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.HResult == -2146232060)
                {
                    msg = $"<strong>Record already exist in the database!</strong>";
                    return msg;
                }
                else
                {
                    msg = $"<strong>Error Message: {ex.HResult}</strong>";
                    return msg;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        msg = $"<strong>Please complete required fields</strong>";
        return msg;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to just return the message string and grab that message once called. thank you!

Comment: Remove 'void' from the method definition: instead of 'private void string InsertRecords' just 'private string InsertRecords'

Comment: thank you that works perfect!

Answer (score 3):

You can't return `string` and have no return value (`void`) at the same time. Since you want to return a value remove `void`

```
private string InsertRecords(TextBox textboxname, string qryname, string parametername) { }
```